# Test Case on Realm (Realm install by CocoaPods)

Tags: cocoapods, realm, testcase

I am using CocoaPods to install the Realm. Then now i need to write the test case for my function.
The problem is the compile can't find the Realm/Realm.h.
Below is my test case.

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "Bookmark.h"

@interface BookmarkTest : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation BookmarkTest
{
    Bookmark *bookmark;
}

- (void)setUp {
[super setUp];
bookmark = [[Bookmark alloc]init];
}
@end
```

Below is my Bookmark class

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
//error shown here:Realm/Realm.h file not found


RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Bookmark)
@interface Bookmark : RLMObject

@property NSString *bId;
@property int type;
@property NSString *mallId;
@property NSString *storeId;
@property NSString *itemId;
@end
```

My podfile,

```
pod 'Realm'
pod 'Realm/Headers'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your Podfile as well? Have you added your test target there?

Comment: I install "pod 'Realm'" & "pod 'Realm/Headers'". After add it test target then how? cannot use default "xxxAppTests"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify your test target in your Podfile as well.
CocoaPods in versions until 0.39 integrates by default only the first target in your project.

The subspec `Realm/Headers` is only thought for test targets with static linking.

Given that your test target, assuming it is named `MyAppTests` links already to your app target what it would usually wit the default setup, your Podfile should look like seen below:

```
target "MyApp" do
    pod "Realm"
end

target "MyAppTests" do
    pod "Realm/Test"
end
```